# Iterate over all rows and find the empty ones of active sheet VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel-worksheet with different "sections" separated by an empty row. What I want to do is to simple get the row numbers to work with them. Sadly the code is not executing the `For`-Loop (No failure, just not entering it) but the `rowNumber` variable is set properly. Did I miss something on the `For`-Loop?

```
Sub Foo()
    Dim currentSheet As Worksheet
    Set currentSheet = activeSheet
    emptyRows = FindAllEmptyRows(currentSheet)
End Sub

Function FindAllEmptyRows(sheet As Worksheet) As Variant
    Dim emptyRows() As Variant
    Dim i As Long, rowNumber As Long
    Dim rowCounter As Integer
    rowCounter = 1

    rowNumber = sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    For i = rowNumber To 1
        If Cells(i, 1).End(xlToRight).Column = 16384 And Cells(i, 1) = "" Then
            emptyRows(rowCounter) = i
            rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
        End If
    Next

    FindAllEmptyRows = emptyRows
End Function
```

Comment: The code doesn't enter the for-loop because the values in the condition are exchanged, you would need to write `For i = 1 To rowNumber` to iterate over all used rows

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to iterate from last row to first you will need to add Step -1.
- `emptyRows()` needs to be sized to fit the data using `ReDim`
- `.Column = 16384` should be changed to `.Column = sheet.Columns.Count`.
- I prefer `If WorksheetFunction.CountA(sheet.Rows(i)) = 0 Then`
- `Cells` needs to be qualified to `sheet`: `sheet.Cells(i, 1)`

### Refactored Code

```
Function FindAllEmptyRows(sheet As Worksheet) As Variant
    Dim emptyRows() As Variant
    Dim i As Long, rowNumber As Long
    Dim rowCounter As Integer

    rowNumber = sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    For i = rowNumber To 1 Step -1
        If sheet.Cells(i, 1).End(xlToRight).Column = sheet.Columns.Count And Cells(i, 1) = "" Then
            If rowCounter = 0 Then
                ReDim emptyRows(0)
            Else
                ReDim Preserve emptyRows(rowCounter)
            End If

            emptyRows(rowCounter) = i
            rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
        End If
    Next

    FindAllEmptyRows = emptyRows
End Function
```

### SpecialCells

`Range.SpecialCells()` can be used to divide a `Range` into areas of cells that meet certain criteria.

[MSDN - Range.SpecialCells Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-specialcells-method-excel)

> Returns a Range object that represents all the cells that match the specified type and value

[OZ Grid](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/special-cells.htm)

> One of the most beneficial Methods in Excel (in my experience) is the SpecialCells Method. When used, it returns a Range Object that represents only those type of cells we specify. For example, one can use the SpecialCells Method to return a Range Object that only contains formulae. In fact, we can, if we wish, even narrow it down further to have our Range Object (containing only formulae) to return only formulae with errors.

Examining the output of this code should give you a good ideas of how to use SpecialCells.

```
Sub SpecialFoo()
    Dim rArea As Range, rBlanks As Range, rFormulas As Range, rConstants As Range, rUnion As Range
    Dim sheet As Worksheet

    Set sheet = ActiveSheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rBlanks = sheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not rBlanks Is Nothing Then
        For Each rArea In rBlanks.Areas
            Debug.Print "rBlanks Areas: "; rArea.Address
        Next
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rFormulas = sheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not rFormulas Is Nothing Then
        For Each rArea In rFormulas.Areas
            Debug.Print "rFormulas Areas: "; rArea.Address
        Next
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rConstants = sheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not rConstants Is Nothing Then
        For Each rArea In rConstants.Areas
            Debug.Print "rConstants Areas: "; rArea.Address
        Next
    End If

    If Not rFormulas Is Nothing And Not rConstants Is Nothing Then
        Set rFormulas = Union(rConstants, rFormulas)
        For Each rArea In rFormulas.Areas
            Debug.Print "rUnion Areas: "; rArea.Address
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to size `emptyRows()` before using it

furthermore you could use `WorksheetFunction.Count()` to check for any value in current row

finally

```
Function FindAllEmptyRows(sheet As Worksheet) As Variant
    Dim emptyRows() As Variant
    Dim i As Long, rowNumber As Long, rowCounter As Long

    With sheet.UsedRange ' reference passed sheet UsedRange
        rowNumber = .Rows.Count
        ReDim emptyRows(0 To rowNumber - 1) ' dim the array to the maximum possible size
        For i = rowNumber To 1 Step -1 ' step through reference range rows from the last baxkwards to the first
            If WorksheetFunction.Count(.Rows(i)) = 0 Then
                emptyRows(rowCounter) = i + .Rows(1).Row - 1 ' fill array in current index with current row index
                rowCounter = rowCounter + 1 ' update array index
            End If
        Next
    End With
    ReDim Preserve emptyRows(0 To rowCounter) ' redim the array according to the actual number of found empty rows

    FindAllEmptyRows = emptyRows
End Function
```

please note that:

```
emptyRows(rowCounter) = i + .Rows(1).Row - 1
```

is storing the *absolute* row index, i.e. the sheet row index, while

```
emptyRows(rowCounter) = i
```

would store the *relative* row index, i.e. the row index withing the `UsedRange`, which may start from a row different than row 1